# jquery datepicker onChangeMonthYear

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, uidatepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using the jquery ui datepicker in my app.
I have created an inline datepicker.
I am having a problem with [onChangeMonthYear](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#event-onChangeMonthYear). I have simplified the example to bare minimum.

Onclick of "prev" or "next", the calendar should: -

1. Go to the previous/next month accordingly.
2. Set the first day of that month as the current selected date.
3. alert that date

The problem is with #2.

I am using [setDate](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#method-setDate) to do that, and it is ending up in infinite recursion. Because, I am calling setDate inside onChangeMonthYear. And setDate is also firing onChangeMonthYear internally.

How can I achieve those 3 things when prev/next is clicked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try setting a flag that you can query in your event handler to prevent the infinite loop:

```
var changingDate = false;
$('.selector').datepicker({
    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
        if (changingDate) {
            return;
        }
        changingDate = true;
        // your setDate() call here
        changingDate = false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The infinite recursion means you are informing the incorrect month.
Make sure you are decreasing 1 from `month`

Comment: Incorrect.  It comes due to the fact that the onChangeMonthYear() also fires on any change.  In this case a setDate() would have caused it, most likely.

Answer (score 0):

```
onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst){
    $(this).datepicker( "setDate", new Date(year, month-1, 1) );
}
```